# how to search exact word in python?

Tags: python, search

I wrote this code to search for an exact word in a text (%PDF-1.1)

```
import re
x = "%PDF-1.1 pdf file contains four parts one of them the header part which looks like "
s = re.compile("%PDF-\d\.\d[\b\s]") 
match = re.search("%PDF-\d\.\d[\b\s]",x)
if match:
    print match.group()
else:
    print "its not found"
```

but the problem is if I have "s%PDF-1.1" it returns the result %PDF-1.1 but it is wrong
and when x =  "pdf file contains four parts one of them the header part which looks like %PDF-1.1" it gives me nothing

how could I search the exact word ????

Comment: Test for `re.compile("^%PDF-\d\.\d[\b\s]")`

Comment: in a string, you have to scape \ symbol, try: `s = re.compile("%PDF-\\d\\.\\d[\\b\\s]") ` and use `s.search(x)` instead of your.

Comment: can you write an example of that case you said it isn't working?

Comment: x = "pdf file contains four parts one of them the header part which looks like %PDF-1.1"

Comment: it is because with your part `[\b\s]` you force to find more thing after the `%PDF-1.1`, and in that case, you have it at the end.

Comment: so how could I find %PDF-1.1 as a whole word neglecting what follow or before it ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you are searching for the word "%PDF-X-X" (Where X is a number) followed by something more without caring about what come before it. If you want to search this word only at the beginning, end of the string or if it is a word (I assume with a space before and after it) you can try this:

```
import re
x = "%PDF-1.1 pdf file contains four parts one of them the header part which looks like "
y = "pdf file contains four parts one of them the header part which looks like %PDF-1.1"
s = re.compile("(^|\s)(?P<myword>%PDF-\d\.\d)($|\s)") 
match = s.search(x)
if match:
    print match.group("myword")
else:
    print "its not found"

match = s.search(y)
if match:
    print match.group("myword")
else:
    print "its not found"

# %PDF-1.1
# %PDF-1.1
```

If you want that the word is also found if it is followed by a symbol, you can make something like this, that allow that it is followed by anything that is not a letter or a number:

```
s = re.compile("(^|\s)(?P<myword>%PDF-\d\.\d)($|\s|[^a-zA-Z0-9])")
```

Comment: If that solved your question, accept the answer so the question doesn't remain as unanswered.

Comment: How canI do that coz  I'm new here